# find indices of duplicate floats in a list

Tags: python, linux, duplicates

I have an input of a very large list of floating point numbers, a sample is given

```
[1.2, 2.4, 3.1, 4.0, 5.6, 6.5, 1.2, 3.1, 8.1, 23.6, 29.3]
```

I want to find all the duplicates and their index i.e. location in the list. The duplicates will only occur as a pair; never more than twice.

The output should be like

```
1.2  1 7
3.1  3 8
```

so there are just two entries 1.2 and 3.1 which occur as duplicates, and their positions are 1, 7 and 3, 8 respectively.

any suggestions with python?

Comment: What a crazy syntax is this? are you sure that is python?

Comment: @xi_  it is for scala, the input is from another software!

Comment: @xi_ you can suggest with python or linux too.. with linux that would just be an os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking xi_'s answer a bit further. By adding the list comprehension it will provide a list of all indices that contain the value.

```
x = [1.2, 2.4, 3.1, 4.0, 5.6, 6.5, 1.2, 3.1, 8.1, 23.6, 29.3]
for el in set(x):
    if x.count(el) > 1:
        print el, " ".join([str(index) for index, value in enumerate(x) if value == el])
```

You will get an output of: (0-based index)

```
1.2 0 6
3.1 2 7
```

**Edit**

Explanation of `[str(index) for index, value in enumerate(x) if value == el]`

This is enumerating `x` which creates an enumerate object of the list which will return tuple pairs of `(<index>, <value>)`

Then it loops through this enumerate object using the `for index, value in enumerate(x)`

The `if value == el` checks each `value` and if it is equal to `el` then we evaluate, otherwise we do nothing.

The `str(index)` is the part that gets evaluated based on the condition we defined above. It returns a string version of `index` which is an integral type.

This will provide a list (all the code between the `[` and `]`) which will then be passed to the string method `join(list)` which joins all of the items in the `list` with the value in the `" "` (in this case a space, it could be any string.) providing a string of space separated values from the list that was created.

I also assume that you may even want this data later on other than just printing it. Here is a version to do that. This creates an empty dictionary `y = {}` then we create a new entry with a key of the value (`el`), providing it a list of the indices.

```
x = [1.2, 2.4, 3.1, 4.0, 5.6, 6.5, 1.2, 3.1, 8.1, 23.6, 29.3]
y = {}
for el in set(x):
    if x.count(el) > 1:
        y[el] = [str(index) for index, value in enumerate(x) if value == el]
```

If you do a `print y` this is what you should get:

```
{3.1: ['2', '7'], 1.2: ['0', '6']}
```

**Edit2**

To print `y` so that it matches the output you specified. Do something like this:

```
print "\n".join(["{} {}".format(key, " ".join(vals)) for key, vals in y.iteritems()])
```

output:

```
3.1 2 7
1.2 0 6
```

What this is doing is iterating through the dictionary `y` with: (`for key, vals in y.iteritems()`) making a string of `"<key> <values...>"` with: (`"{} {}".format(key, " ".join(vals))`) This returns a list of strings so we join them using `"\n"` to make them on each line.

Now it is important to note that since dictionary is a hash, that your output order of the keys will not be sorted. If you want to do that, then you could change the code above to this:

```
print "\n".join(["{} {}".format(key, " ".join(y[key])) for key in sorted(y.keys())])
```

output:

```
1.2 0 6
3.1 2 7
```

Comment: is it possible for you to explain your code a bit so that I can modify it later for different purpose?  the last one liner is not clear to me after join

Comment: Why is the output in form [(0.11004363790442408, '0 22'), (1.0003303788789184, '1 7'), (0.9427256865065468, '15 23')]  ? why not without comma etc?

Comment: The output is in that form with commas because it is printing a standard representation of the data type. If you want the output to look "pretty" then you will have to iterate through and print. I have included that in the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like that:

```
x = [1.2, 2.4, 3.1, 4.0, 5.6, 6.5, 1.2, 3.1, 8.1, 23.6, 29.3]
for el in set(x):
    if x.count(el) > 1:
        print el, x.count(el), len(x) - x[::-1].index(el)
```

Output (element with duplicates, quantity, index of last occurrence):

```
1.2 2 7
3.1 2 8
```

Comment: it is already known that there would be 2 occurrences, however, the indexes of the occurrences are important!

Comment: @HamadHassan you need all indeces?

Comment: yes, I need all the indexes to see at which location a certain value is repeated!